# handling three tables with two one-to-many relationship among them

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database, entity-relationship

I have a three tables, A, B and C. A has many B, and B has many C. What is the best way design primary keys and relationship among these two. Sorry to ask a designing problem, but I don't know whether to use

1. one extra table to map A(pkey) - B(pkey) - C(pkey) OR
2. two exta tables to map A-B and B-C separately OR
3. use foreign key relationships without using any extra tables (if so please tell me how the key columns should come)

Thank you very much.

Comment: Is B always dependent on A?  Stated another way can a B exist without an A?  If B cannot exist without A then maybe the PK for B should also include the FK from A.  If the same with C then maybe the PK for B (which includes the PK for A) should also be in the PK for C.

Comment: Thanks its a valuable point! Yes B cannot exist without A and the same for B and C. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option (3) sounds like the most natural:

```
A: { id, *, *, ... };

B: { id, a_id references(A.id), *, *, ... }

C: { id, b_id references(B.id), *, *, ... }
```

To query:

```
SELECT ... FROM A JOIN B ON (A.id = B.a_id) JOIN C ON (B.id = C.b_id);
```

Always make your database model the logical relationships in your data, not the other way round!

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick and clear response with the SQL Query.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use three. THere's no need for additional tables in a 1:many relationship. The many-side holds a foreign key pointing to the one-side.

Answer (score 2):

Option 3 is the way to go.

```
A {a_pk, ...}
B {b_pk, ..., a_pk_as_fk}
C {c_pk, ..., b_pk_as_fk}
```